# Binding in ResourceDictionary not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `ContextMenu` in a `ResourceDictionary`. The `ContextMenu` should hide or show depending on the value of a view-model property, but it does not work.

This is my *XAML* code (`ControlBase` derives from `UserControl`):

```
<control1:ControlBase>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding InfraNetworkItems}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext,
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                      Visibility="{Binding
                                          DataContext.MyViewModel.DeleteEnabled,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                              AncestorType=control1:ControlBase},
                                          Converter={StaticResource
                                              BooleanVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</control1:ControlBase>
```

`DeleteEnabled` is a `bool` property on the view-model.

---

My previous attempts of solving the problem are based on this assumptions:

The `ContextMenu` is inside a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` which has the `ItemsSource` set. My property is not a member of this `ItemSource`, it belongs to the view-model. Therefore I've tried this line of code, but without any effect:

```
Visibility="{Binding DataContext.MyViewModel.DeleteEnabled,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=control1:ControlBase},
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
```

But if I copy the `DeleteEnabled` property from the view-model to the `ItemSource` object, it works:

```
Visibility="{Binding DeleteEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the DataContext of your view? If it's an instance of MyViewModel you have to change the path of your Binding.
Please try this one:

```
<Visibility="{Binding DataContext.DeleteEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=control1:ControlBase}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

With setting the path to DataContext you already have access to your viewmodel and of course to the DeleteEnabled-Property.
Hope this helps.